# Maximum simultaneous Server-sent events (SSE) connections to a web server (Nginx + ExpressJS)

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

How many Server-sent event connections can be handled by an Ubuntu server with:

1. 1 GB of RAM
2. Dual-core CPU
3. Running Nginx (as a reverse proxy)
4. In front of ExpressJS server?

Topics I have was able to study about:

1. Difference between Websockets and Server-sent events.
2. Limitations imposed by browsers for SSE (max 6 for one domain).
3. Headers that need to be mentioned in the proxy configuration for Nginx.
4. Configuring workers for Nginx.
5. Node.js is a better choice for SSE instead of PHP.
6. Nginx being among the few servers to address the C10K problem.

I did not find any real stats or case studies about how many simultaneous connections can be handled by a server (may be with the above mentioned specs and configuration or ... some other higher/lower spec configuration)

Comment: This is probably not answerable here. [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Hello @EsaJokinen, no that is not true. I have found exact answer for my question.